# Shuggy crashes on launch with 'FileNotFound' error?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, adventures-of-shuggy

I've just tried installing the Adventures of Shuggy demo on Steam, but unfortunately it crashes immediately after launch with the message

> Shuggy has stopped working

Here's a screenshot of how the crash looks like:

[image: shuggy crash]

Upon examining Windows event viewer logs, I see that a .NET Runtime error was reported:

> Application: Shuggy.exe
>   Framework Version: v4.0.30319
>   Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
>   Exception Info: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
>   Stack:
>     at Shuggy.Program.Main(System.String[])

My usual approach for launch errors of Steam games, validating the local file integrity, didn't help. Does anyone know how to address this issue? System is Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and installing the redistributables from the install directory fixed it for me.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not solved the crash I am experiencing.